# Python-lunch Syntax Error: except ImportError , e:

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I just installed lunch (with the command "pip install lunch"), but when I run the command "lunch" I just get this error everytime:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
  File "/usr/bin/lunch", line 41, in <module>

    from lunch import runner

  File "/home/xor/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lunch/runner.py", line 73

    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That's Python 2 syntax. This project was written for Python 2 only, and hasn't been maintained for what looks like about 6 years. Its homepage is a dead URL. Find something else to use.

Comment: Thanks, I have set my default Python to Python 2.7, and it worked. Surprisingly, after I ran it once, it now even works with Python 3